# Small set vs logical or in Scala

Tags: scala, set

I'm seeing something like this in Scala code:

```
if (Set("foo", "bar").contains(x)) { ... }
```

An obvious alternative would be a simple OR condition:

```
if (x == "foo" || x == "bar") { ... }
```

Apart from arguably better readability, what are the objective benefits of using the original approach? Is it more performant / consumes less memory / etc?

Couple things to note:

1. In the real code, "foo" and "bar" are fixed instances of a case class
2. There are just two elements in the condition. The likelihood of adding more elements in future is low.

Comment: IMHO the main point is readibility and this depends on the context: _"x equals foo or bar"_ is semantically not the same as _"x is part of a set of possibilities that includes foo or bar"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason why I would recommend using the former approach is if the set is somehow configurable or if it's so large and full of complex data that it actually helps.

If that was the case, I would still give it a name and leverage the fact that `contains` is also aliased as `apply` for `Set`s to make it more readable (and avoid creating a lot of very short-lived data):

```
val isFooOrBar: String => Boolean = Set("foo", "bar")

if (isFooOrBar(x)) { ... }
```

As for performance:

1. there is a highly likelihood that this is not critical
2. if it is critical, the only source of truth is measuring

In that regard, I'm quite sure that the `||` is very likely to perform better (no data to create, less layers of abstraction, very well understood by the runtime and the JIT, etc.) but even if that's the case, I would focus on readability. If the `case class`es are quite large, you might not want to embed the whole thing in the `if` condition, but nothing prevents you from doing the following:

```
def isFooOrBar(x: String): Boolean = x == "foo" || x == "bar"

if (isFooOrBar(x)) { ... }
```

which makes it indistinguishable at call-site what approach you took and is arguably readable anyway. Maybe the only improvement is to give the predicate a name that described more accurately the *why*, like in the following made-up snippet:

```
// anything but "foo" and "bar" are incompatible with the retroencabulator
def isCompatibleWithRetroencabulator(s: String) = ...
```

And if you *really* care about performance, make it `private` and perhaps annotate it with `@inline` (and measure). ;-)

Comment: I guess `Set` could be faster if: 1) you stored it in a `val` to allocate it only once, 2) it was large enough that pointer-chaising in the internal tree would not overshadow gains from doing a logarithmic number of equality tests. Rather unlikely. It would be easier to justify it with a readability if there were more than 2 elements, or if names would be particularly long.

Comment: I am here to second your remarks about performance. Either version is reasonably efficient. It is highly unlikely that it would matter either way, performance-wise. 99% of the time readability is much more important than the nanoseconds you might save at runtime.